# Moved site, make old links redirect with .htaccess? From sub.mydomain.com to mydomain.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web, migration, symlink

I recently moved my blog from

`http://blog.mydomain.com`

to

`http://mydomain.com`

My problem now is that I have sites linking to the old addresses.

What can I put in my .htaccess file to make, for instance,

`http://blog.mydomain.com/my-post-title-here`

go to

`http://mydomain.com/my-post-title-here`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question. I put this in the root of the 'blog' subdomain:

```
rewriteEngine on
rewriteBase /
rewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.mydomain.com$
rewriteRule ^(.*) http://mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```